# Acidic Strength comparison

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I wanted to compare the acidic strength of aniline and water.

Water on losing hydrogen gives $OH^-$ and aniline on releasing H gives $\ce{Ph-NH-}$ and this -ve charge goes into resonance so the -ve charge is distributed, then which one is has more acidic strength??

If it is aniline then it should react with $\ce{NaOH}$, since water, which is comparatively weaker acid is formed as a product, then why does it not do so

Please tell me if i am wrong somewhere in my logic and which one is more acidic.

[NOTE: I am a class 12th student, so please try to keep the answer within the scope of a 12th grade student's knowledge]

Comment: You need **two** phenyl rings to get amine with acidity comparable to water (diphenylamine).

Comment: Usually what we call the Ka of aniline is the value of the anilinium $\ce{C6H5NH3^+}$ cation

Comment: The pKa of aniline is ~30 that of water is 14. pKa is logarhythmic scale so the aniline proton is approx 10^16 less acidic than water

Answer (score 1):

Actually whether aniline will react with $\ce{NaOH}$ or not will depend on what medium we choose for the reaction.

If it is $\ce{dil. NaOH}$ then the $\ce{OH-}$ dissociated will be solvated so that it will no longer be a base however will be a neucleophile but as $\ce{-NH2}$ is attached at a $\ce{sp2}$ centre so can't do substitution reactions.

And if it is $\ce{conc. NaOH}$ or the medium is alcohol or polar aprotic then it can do acid-base reaction.

Comment: That's a good point. Even if OP's issue is more of "lets just get a hold on water pKa", it may be good to find its limitations early on.